# How to Model self-referential Entities in SQL

Tags: sql, erd

*for a practical example, Let's consider trying to model Pokemon elements in SQL.*

One element has many strengths and weaknesses, but they themselves are also of type element.  How would you model that in a Database?

I believe the solution would be to create an extra 2 tables, perhaps element_strength and element_weakness which would work like joining tables in a many-many relationship. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be it, but you can simplify:

Table Element
idElement | name

Table Weakness
idRow | idElement |idElementStrongAgainst

No need to add a strength table, you just have to look at the weakness table entering by the other column.

So to find the strengths of water you do

```
SELECT strVS.Name 
FROM Element AS el
JOIN Weakness on el.idElement = Weakness.idElement
JOIN Element As strVS on weakness.idElementStrongAgainst= strVS.idElement
WHERE el.Name = 'water'
```

and to find the weaknesses:

```
SELECT weakVS.Name 
FROM Element AS el
JOIN Weakness on el.idElement = Weakness.idElementStrongAgainst
JOIN Element As weakVS on weakness.idElement = weakVS.idElement
WHERE el.Name = 'water'
```

Comment: Perfect! the only thing is that Strong and weak against aren't a 2 way thing, so water may do 2x damage to fire, but fire doesn't do half damage against water.

Comment: Oh, then you do need a different table to diferentiate when it does half damage or normal damage. Because this one only specifies that this element always does double damage vs the other element.

Comment: aye, that's all specifics though, as far as an entity referencing itself this is the solution I'm looking for, thanks!